# Is potential energy an energy exists or potentiality of energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I want to ask whether Potential Energy is truly existing Energy - though i know the energy concept is abstract and we do not know what is energy truly as Feynman said - or it is the potentiality that the body will gain energy in the future , i do not mean to be philosophical question but really i want to know that point, and if we can give the potential energy concept away and formulate the laws in other way ?

Comment: Define *"truly existing Energy"*.

Comment: very good question but i think i do not know maybe Kinetic energy ?

Comment: To add some impact to this question... what kinds of energy count as mass-energy? Does potential energy exert a gravitational pull?

Comment: For concreteness, consider a particle of mass $m$ attached to an ideal spring of spring constant $k$ compressed a distance $\Delta x$.  Accordingly, there is a potential energy $U = \frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x^2)$.  Now, in this context, what is your question?

Comment: my question is : you said " there is a potential energy " i'm asking if the Energy is truly inside it or it means there is a potential for gaining Energy in the future if you let it go.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is the case that I don't understand what "the energy is truly inside" *means* or the distinction that you're making.

Comment: i mean the KE has an effect right now not in the future , that what i mean

Answer (score 2):

I see the viewpoint you're coming from. From the wording of "potential energy", it sounds like the energy might not exist until it becomes kinetic energy. Potential energy is as real as kinetic energy though. The idea is that the energy gets stored in the fields that produce the force, and that the energy is transferred between kinetic energy and field energy. This is most evident in electromagnetics. Common electronic components, capacitors and inductors, store energy in electric and magnetic fields respectively.

The picture with gravity gets more complicated though, because gravity is described by general relativity, which does away with energy concepts. It's not really my field, so I can't comment further than that.

Edit: To answer, "Do the fields really exist, or are they a just a mathematical tool?", yes, they do exist. Light for example, is an electromagnetic wave, which can transfer both energy and momentum. In a quantum mechanics view, this is a discrete particle known as a photon, which interacts similarly to any other particle. As an assurance that photons are real, there's something known as pair production: high energy photons can spontaneously form pairs of particles such as electrons and positrons. At this point, I would believe that the fields are as real as electrons and positrons.

Alfred Centauri's comment is also a good answer as to why we think the fields are real.

Comment: So you want to say that fields are truly existing  " objects " like matter ? or it is a mathematical tool ? same question for electric and magnetic flux do they exist or tools to analyze ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama, *something* exists that can be mathematically *modelled*, with great success, as electric and magnetic fields that store, release, and transport energy and momentum.  To deny that is to deny the physical evidence.  The question of what precisely that something *is* (rather than "does it truly exist?") is a metaphysical question beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Well your question was not perfect, but acceptable. the idea of energy may sound easy, but deeply it is a very strange Idea.

but the answer to your question: no it doesn't mean it "potentially" gonna gain. I see that you read Feynman's lectures, that's very good, but these speeches actually are for people who accepted the idea of energy blindly, and didn't think hard enough to see how abstract it could be.

See it is just the matter of modeling. we model the world around us in the "matter and energy" phenomena. there is something named Energy that let the objects move. that's the first clue of the energy! but we will encounter with a problem:

Imagine a you are holding the ball in the air. it is not moving, so we say"Okay it doesn't have any ENERGY right now" but as soon as you let it go it start to move! but how? it gained energy some how. from where?

this is when the **potential energy** comes to the mind. when you grab the ball and raised it to a level, some energy is stored inside! some energy that is potential in it and ready to go out of the object as soon as you let the ball go. this potential energy in this example is called **Gravitational potential energy** . because it is due to the gravity.

but the potential energy can be used in so many places. like electrical potential. generally a moving object has energy. the energy that the object has due to it's movement is called **Kinetic energy** with the sign of $k$ . but for a non-moving object it doesn't mean it doesn't mean that it doesn't have any energy. there is some energy stored **Inside** the object that we call **Potential energy** and we show it with letter $U$ .

and the most famous equation is this : $E=U+k$ . and it means any mechanical energy that an object is the sum of energy inside and the energy due to it's movement! and we can say **the total amount of energy doesn't change**.

the energy turns from inside energy to kinetic or another way around, but it never changes.

so the word potential is for"potential to move". the energy that is stored inside the object that we can not see.

Comment: Ok , let me ask something you said " it does not mean it has no Energy " i can argue as the following , the ball has no energy when you are graping it the statics come to play two forces cancel each other but when you left it , it has no energy but there is a resultant force that will push it and make work on it and "give" it Kinetic Energy , the problem is i can't imagine " stored in it " plus the potential energy is associated for systems not single isolated particles.
Does you question imply that physics is just modelling and not as they call it "ontological "  or something like that?

Comment: @MohamedOsama Yes excatly.your way of explaining is right too. see that's the general dynamic.we know these days that this things doesn't apply to so many things, like small objects such as electrons.and yes your modeling is correct too. see that you are also modeling the movement somehow. I say a potential energy is stored,you say a force is applied, and these too models actually one thing explained in two different ways.

energy is a useful method for us to model the world. to understand things.it is not clear for you the "internal" energy,and that's the reason why feynman say it's abstract.

Comment: @MohamedOsama it is not because it doesn't exist, but if we want to think about the concept, it is a strange but useful way to model the world. physics is ontological, but not in mechanics all the way. there are so many strange abstract phenomena like temperature that help us to model the "Macroscopic" world easily. remember there is a microscopic explanation for each phenomena too. you can not say a macroscopic idea is wrong because it doesn't answer the microscopic questions.

Comment: Although i'm not 100% satisfied but thanks anyway

Comment: @MohamedOsama pleasure to help you. but see, some physics phenomena are not there to satisfy us. or show us the so called "true" world. or the way that things are, some ideas are there for us to help us calculate and predict the movements! if it can help us predict and calculate the world then they are "Useful" ideas and phenomena. and still there are some theories to help us understand the world the way it is.

Comment: is it allowed in physics to ask the question of " Does X truly exist or it is just a tool or model " ?

Comment: @MohamedOsama that's a very important philosophical question that you have. in my own opinion we are not finding the world's "truth" . what every we get about the world is the Human's version of understanding of the world. who knows what lies in the nature that we can't absorb. and the physics of the older age was used only as a tool! until the modern age of physics with quantum mechanics that goes deeper in the world's mechanic. and yes some X are only tools, some are "more" realistic and convinced. and some are both.